# Matrix manipulation in Excel/R

Tags: r, excel, matrix

I have a very large adjacency matrix in the following format, whereby the numbers indicate the number of times each person in the row has won against the person in the column.

```
Loser/Winner Steve Joe Chan Jess
       Steve   0    2   8    4
         Joe   8    0   2    5
        Chan   9    5   0    6
        Jess   4    6   9    0
```

I want to convert this to a matrix of net wins in either R or Excel. 
So, for this particular example the output would be:

```
Loser/Winner Steve Joe Chan Jess
       Steve   0   -6   -1    0
         Joe   6    0   -3   -1
        Chan   1    3    0   -3
        Jess   0    1    3    0
```

Comment: can you provide your data in a copy-friendly format, like using `dput(mat)`?

Comment: You've the stored the given matrix in some object, right? If its name is `mat`, `dput(mat)` should provide a copy-paste friendly structure. You can also use `datapasta` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it does what you want.

```r
mat <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  Loser_Winner = c("Steve", "Joe", "Chan", "Jess"),
                  Steve = c(0, 8, 9, 4),
                  Joe = c(2, 0, 5, 6),
                  Chan = c(8, 2, 0, 9),
                  Jess = c(4, 5, 6, 0))

win_matrix <- as.matrix(x = mat[, -1])
loss_matrix <- t(x = win_matrix)
net_win <- as.data.frame(x = (win_matrix - loss_matrix))

net_win
#>   Steve Joe Chan Jess
#> 1     0  -6   -1    0
#> 2     6   0   -3   -1
#> 3     1   3    0   -3
#> 4     0   1    3    0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Provided your data is already in `matrix` form, this is simply

```
mat - t(mat)
#      Steve Joe Chan Jess
#Steve     0  -6   -1    0
#Joe       6   0   -3   -1
#Chan      1   3    0   -3
#Jess      0   1    3    0
```

---

### Sample data

```
mat <- as.matrix(read.table(text =
    "Steve Joe Chan Jess
       Steve   0    2   8    4
         Joe   8    0   2    5
        Chan   9    5   0    6
        Jess   4    6   9    0", header = T))
```

Comment: This is same as my answer.

Comment: @yarnabrina It's similar. I'm avoiding the whole `data.frame` excess. Since OP has an adjacency matrix, there's no need to work with `data.frame`s. For larger objects the performance increase from working with matrices (instead of `data.frame`s) can be very significant. Since the solution is really rather trivial here, focus should be placed on clean and performant code.